# Qt "connect" syntax is very long. Is it any tricks to make it shorter?

Tags: qt

In C# in order to connect a signal to slot (delegate to method) all i do is:

```
first.signal += second.slot
```

But in Qt it is:

```
connect( & first, SIGNAL( signal( int, int, QString ) ), & second, SLOT( slot( int, int, QSTring ) ) );
```

And this one is counted short, normally they are spawned 2-3 lines. Of course i fully understood that Qt mocks only .h files and for .cpp they are bound to standard syntax, but is it any tricks / ways to make signal-slot connectons a bit shorter? I know about auto-connecting signals to slots by giving them special names, but this works only for signals in .ui file. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick would be to use QtCreator as an editor, as it lets you pick signals and slots from a drop-down-list as you type.

A seemingly unrelated reflection is that Qt strives to have a rather verbose API, as it is easier to read (and to remember when writing). Thus, they avoid abbreviations and write what they mean: QAbstractItemModel, setWindowTitle, etc. Not QAbstItModel, setWinTit, etc. More typing, less misunderstandings and linker errors (missing symbols)

Comment: QtCreator can only connect Gui signals and slots, or any one?

Comment: When typing "connect(src, SIGNAL(", you get a list of signals available... same for SLOT(...

Answer (score 6):

> I know about auto-connecting signals to slots by giving them special names, but this works only for signals in .ui file

That approach can be used outside of .ui files, you can call [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) anywhere you want.

Comment: Just be careful how and when you call it... if you do that in a base-class constructor, then again in a derived-class constructor (for instance), you might end up with some slots connected twice.  It doesn't distinguish those connected already when it is run.  (You can probably guess how I now know that.)

Answer (score 3):

If you find that long and repetitive, you could use macros to make the syntax lighter. For example:

```
#define S_i_i(x) x(int, int, QString)
#define CONNECT(sx,x,tx,sy,y,ty) connect(&x, SIGNAL(tx(sx)), &y, SLOT(ty(sy)))

CONNECT(signal, first, S_i_i, slot, second, S_i_i)
```

The drawback is that your code will lose in readability for others unless you choose your macros carefully.

Comment: I think it's debatable to say that this syntax is lighter... Using this approach you would need a #define for each signal signature. The only place where this `might` be useful would be if you need to connect multiple slots to the same signal, and in that case you've already written one connect(...) and a simple copy/paste will do.

Comment: @daniel: what the OP wanted is _shorter_ code. There aren't that many signatures, and they could be defined once for all in a common header, like for common delegates in C#. That being said, I don't find the original Qt way of coding signals and slots annoying in the first place and would rather stick to it, but that's just a matter of personal preference :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing connections from a signal in a *different* object to a slot in *`this`* object, you can do a shortcut, and use this:

```
connect( & first, SIGNAL( signal( int, int, QString ) ), SLOT( slot( int, int, QSTring ) ) );
```

instead of this:

```
connect( & first, SIGNAL( signal( int, int, QString ) ), & second, SLOT( slot( int, int, QSTring ) ) );
```

which removes a little bit of the connection.  There are other shortcuts available as well, I believe.  However, your general point is valid, and is mostly a side-effect of how Qt does their signal/slot mechanism.  If you really want a more terse syntax in C++, you could look at either the Boost::Signals or SigC++ libraries, which also provide a signal/slot mechanism.  Be aware of syntax conflicts, however.

Comment: Boost::Signals don't integrate well in Qt, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't think it's that bad. You only have to write it once for each signal/slot and most of the time you don't have to touch it afterwards.

The closest thing I found that helps in someway is using boost::bind/function with the signals/slots mechanism. It doesn't provide a direct answer to your question but it is related and you might make use of it. You can read about it [here](http://uint32t.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-boost-bind-and-boost-function.html).

Answer (score 0):

After a few years i have found a kind of solution that can make connections shorter. Solution is based on @WildSeal 's answer and uses this simple macro:

```
#define QCON( a, b, c, d ) VERIFY( QObject::connect( a, SIGNAL(b), c, SLOT(d) ) )
```

So, the long code in question:

```
VERIFY( QObject::connect( first, SIGNAL(signal(int,int,QString)), second, SLOT(slot(int,int,QSTring)) ) );
```

Will became significantly shorter:

```
QCON( first, signal(int,int,QString), second, slot(int,int,QString) );
```

Any comments and suggestions are welcome :). The only drawbacks i have found right now is that i need a separate macro to connect SIGNAL to SIGNAL. But since such operation is kind of rare i just introduced `QCONS()` and it does a trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for Qt5 and C++11-enabled compilers:

```
#define Q_CONNECT(sender, signal, receiver, slot) \
    QWidget::connect( \
        sender, &boost::remove_reference<boost::mpl::identity<decltype(*sender)>::type>::type::signal, \
        receiver, &boost::remove_reference<boost::mpl::identity<decltype(*receiver)>::type>::type::slot);

#define Q_CONNECT_LAMBDA(sender, signal, receiver) \
    QWidget::connect( \
    sender, &boost::remove_reference<boost::mpl::identity<decltype(*sender)>::type>::type::signal, \
    receiver);
```

Note that boost::mpl::identity is only needed for compilers that don't yet handle the following (like VS2010):

```
decltype(expr)::member
```

Usage example:

```
Q_CONNECT(
    this, mySignalMethodName,
    &someHandler, handlerMethodName);

Q_CONNECT_LAMBDA(
    this, mySignalMethodName,
    [=]() { handlerCode(); });
```

Pros:

- no need to type in argument lists;
- no need to explicitly duplicate type information;
- no need to use any of SIGNAL, SLOT, Q_SIGNAL, Q_SLOT macros;
- all compatibility checks are compile-time.

Cons:

- won't work with overloaded methods.